# Как получить индентификаторы AUTO_INCREMENT при многострочном INSERT?

Tags: sql, php, mysql

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите, возможно ли получить идентификаторы вставленных строк (желательно средствами PHP), если они вставляются без блокировки таблицы (myisam)?

```
INSERT INTO table (row1, row1) VALUES(2, 3), (5, 2), (7, 9);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял то вам надо `mysql_insert_id` , для PDO `lastInsertId();`

Если же надо при множественной вставке- то тут встроенных решений нет (по крайней мере мне неизвестно), но попробуйте вот так

`mysql_insert_id()` выдаст первый идентификатор

`mysql_insert_id() + 2` - выдаст последний идентификатор - это именно в твоем случае. - то есть прибавляем (N-1), где N кол -во вставляемых данных.

Немного погуглив вот что нашел

```
/**
* Возвращает список всех вставленных ID с помощью multiInsert()
**/
function get_all_insert_id($countLines) {
  $arID = array();
  for ($i = mysql_insert_id(); $i <= (mysql_insert_id() + $countLines); $i++) {
    $arID[] = $i;
  }

  return $arID;
}
```

Comment: Правильно, да не совсем. Этот способ вернет идентификатор только одной строки из 3-х вставленных, а мне нужно все 3.

Comment: Этот способ в принципе очевиден, но он мне кажется имеет место быть как раз только с блокировкой таблиц. Потому как можно же параллельно вставлять несколькими такими запросами, и идентификаторы могут пересекаться.

В любом случае благодарю за помощь, буду пробовать!

Comment: по поводу пересечений вставки - как говорят их не может быть на myisam, вот тут гляньте http://forum.searchengines.ru/archive/index.php/t-596333.html

Answer (score 0):

Наверное чисто средствами PHP нельзя. Отправляйте запрос типа: SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3

Comment: Не, вообще не то. Проблему вопроса не решает